# Tiled background image doesn't tile over the entire page

Tags: css, background, background-image

For some reason my tiled image doesn't tile over the whole background. Though it fills the whole background when I resize the window a little bit.

The background is set in css.

```
body {
  background: url(img/tile.gif) #e6e6e6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This is in Chrome and Safari, so webkit. Works fine in Firefox.

[image: tile img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
body{
 background-image: url(img/tile.gif);
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(img/tile.gif) repeat #e6e6e6;
```